# redirecting woocommerce product image to custom URL instead of Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, affiliate, webstore

I am new to WordPress and trying woocommerce to create an affiliate store. Generally, when we click on a product in woocommerce it leads to the product page. I want it to go to custom URL that is the affiliated link instead of the Product page.

Can anyone please help me to get this. I looked on web and find out method to remove the product page but not the redirection to url part.

Thanks.

Comment: admin panel.... select the product as Virtual product and there will be a field to enter your link (actual product link)

Comment: @Alice Hey Thanks for your response but it is not showing any place to put the affiliated link.